# django many-to-many field: prefetch primary keys only

Tags: python, database, django, optimization, django-queryset

I'm trying to optimize database queries for a Django app. Here's a simplified example:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ... many other fields ...

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label)
```

I have a function that fetches all `Label`s and `Thing`s and puts them into a JSON data structure, in which `Thing`s refer to `Label`s using their `id`s (primary keys). Something like this:

```
{
    'labels': [
        { 'id': 123, 'name': 'label foo' },
        ...
    ],
    'things': [
        { 'id': 45, 'name': 'thing bar', 'labels': [ 123, ... ] },
        ...
    ]
}
```

What is the most efficient way of obtaining such a data structure using Django? Suppose I have **L** `Label`s and **T** `Thing`s, and the average `Thing` has **x** `Label`s.

**Method 1:**

```
data = {}
data['labels'] = [model_to_dict(label) for label in Label.objects.all()]
data['things'] = [model_to_dict(thing) for thing in Thing.objects.all()]
```

This makes (1 + 1 + **T**) database queries, since `model_to_dict(thing)` needs to fetch the `Label`s for each `Thing` individually.

**Method 2:**

```
data = {}
data['labels'] = [model_to_dict(label) for label in Label.objects.all()]
data['things'] = [model_to_dict(thing) for thing in
                    Thing.objects.prefetch_related('labels').all()]
```

This makes (1 + 1 + 1) database queries only, since the `Thing`s fetched now have their `Label`s prefetched in a single additional query.

**This is still not satisfactory.** `prefetch_related('labels')` will fetch many copies of the same `Label`, whereas I only need their `id`s. Is there any way to prefetch the `id`s of the `Label`s only? I tried `prefetch_related('labels__id')` but that didn't work. I am also concerned that because **T** is large (hundreds), `prefetch_related('labels')` results in a SQL query with a large `IN` clause. **L** is much smaller (< 10), so I could do this instead:

**Method 3:**

```
data = {}
data['labels'] = [model_to_dict(label) for label in
                    Label.objects.prefetch_related('thing_set').all()]
things = list(Thing.objects.all())
# plug in label ids by hand, and also fetch things that have zero labels
# somehow
```

This results in a smaller `IN` clause, but is still not satisfactory because `prefetch_related('thing_set')` fetches duplicate `Thing`s, if a `Thing` has multiple `Label`s.

**Summary:**

`Label` and `Thing` are connected by a `ManyToManyField`. I am fetching **all** `Label`s and `Thing`s anyway. So how do I also fetch their many-to-many relationship efficiently?

Comment: Maybe try using intermediary model for m2m? DB scheme and anything else will stay the same but you'll be able to `fetch_related` only this model and take label's ID from it. If you'll link it with `through` argument to M2M some methods like `add()` will be broken, but you can manually provide `db_table` for it and don't touch m2m field, so it should work.

Comment: Thanks @ilvar, your comment led me to the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it. Thanks to ilvar, whose comment to the question pointed me to [`through` tables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

> If you don’t specify an explicit through model, there is still an
>   implicit through model class you can use to directly access the table
>   created to hold the association. It has three fields to link the
>   models.

Long story short:

```
# Fetch all labels and things:
labels = list(Label.objects.all())
things = list(Thing.objects.all())
# Fetch all label-thing pairs:
labels_of = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for pair in Thing.labels.through.objects.filter(label__in=labels):
    labels_of[pair.thing_id].append(pair.label_id)
# Put everything together:
data = {}
data['labels'] = [model_to_dict(label) for label in labels]
data['things'] = []
for thing in things:
    thing_dict = model_to_dict(thing, exclude='labels')
    thing_dict['labels'] = labels_of[thing.id]
    data['things'].append(thing_dict)
```

This makes (1 + 1 + 1) queries, and does not fetch anything repeatedly. I can also change the first for loop to:

```
for pair in Thing.labels.through.objects.filter(thing__in=things):
```

in case I have more `Label`s than `Thing`s, which will result in a query with a smaller `IN` clause.

[Django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)'s `debugsqlshell` management command is superb for actually seeing the queries that a piece of code is making.